# Check duplicates from a state hook in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out on how to remove duplicates from an array of objects when entering multiple input skill tags. Maybe I am missing some key points here

```
const SkillsTags = ({ skillTags, setSkillTags, skill }) => {
  const removeSkillTag = (i) => {
    setSkillTags([...skillTags.filter((_, index) => index !== i)]);
  };

  const addSkillTag = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var updatedSkills = [...skillTags];

    if (skill.current.value.trim().length !== 0) {
      updatedSkills = [...skillTags, { SKILL_NAME: skill.current.value }];
    }

    setSkillTags(updatedSkills);
    skill.current.value = "";
  };

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="Skills">Skills:</label>
      <div className="input-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Skills (Press Enter to add)"
          onKeyPress={(e) => (e.key === "Enter" ? addSkillTag(e) : null)}
          ref={skill}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={addSkillTag}>
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
      <ul style={{ height: "12.5rem" }}>
        {skillTags.map((val, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              {val.SKILL_NAME}
              <button type="button" onClick={() => removeSkillTag(index)}>
                Remove
              </button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-skill-tags-nitthd?file=/src/SkillsTags.js

Comment: Are you necessarily looking to "remove duplicates from an array" or are you just looking to check if a value exists in that array before adding it?  Either way this seems to be less about React and more about JavaScript logic in general.  Can you clarify?

Comment: More like entering a value in an input and then checking a value that exists in an array then it ignores to add whenever there are duplicate values. And I am using [skillTags, setSkillTags] = useState([]) while useRef for skill variable which was placed in another component. I put skill = useRef() so that I wont be rerender every time a keypress occurs in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to filter duplicates, You can achieve this with simple `Javascript`.

```
const addSkillTag = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const isDuplicate = skillTags.some(function (item, idx) {
      return item.SKILL_NAME === skill.current.value;
    });

    if (skill.current.value.trim().length !== 0) {
      if (!isDuplicate) {
        skillTags = [...skillTags, { SKILL_NAME: skill.current.value }];
      }
    }

    setSkillTags(skillTags);
    skill.current.value = "";
  };
```